# logic behind creating plots under ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

If I may ask a kind of abstract question [supported by a specific example] about correct logic while building complicated charts in R using `ggplot`. For instance, I need to create a chart like this: 
[image]

The logical steps I have in my mind are the following: 
First, I melt my data from wide to long format using melt() function.
Second, I create a ggplot() script adding `data = , aes(x=date, y=value, colour = variable, shape = variable) , size = , stat = 'identity'` to `geom_line()` and `geom_point()`.
Third, I add `scale_shape_manual` and `scale_colour_manual` to customize my chart and legend.

Although I'm pretty sure that it will give me a desired chart I have many doubts the legend would be depicted the way I need. In particular, having scale_colour_manual for both points and line for the same chart would result in duplicated records in the legend: for points and for line.

Below is one of my scripts that produces a chart I need along with the problem with the legend:

p8_ch2_points_melt contains data for points, 
p8_ch2_line_melt contains data for line.

```
p8.2_rest <- ggplot() + 
    geom_point(data = p8_ch2_points_melt, aes(x=date, y=value, colour = variable, shape= variable), size = 1, stat = 'identity') + 
  geom_line (data = p8_ch2_line_melt, aes(x=date, y=value, colour = variable), size = 1, stat = 'identity') +

scale_shape_manual (
  guide = "legend", 
  name = NULL,
  breaks= c('eff_int', 'int'), 
  labels= c('Эффективная ставка, % годовых (левая ось)', 'Стоимость суверенных займов, % годовых (левая ось)'),
  values = c(15,20))+

 scale_colour_manual (
  guide = "legend", 
  name = NULL,
  breaks= c('eff_int', 'int', 'debt_serv'), 
  labels= c('Эффективная ставка, % годовых (левая ось)', 'Стоимость суверенных займов, % годовых (левая ось)', 'Обслуживание долга, % от ВВП (левая ось)'),
  values = c('#4477AA', '#117733', '#332288'))
```

And here the chart it produces:

[image]

And here are dput() for 2 data frames:

```
dput(p8_ch2_points_melt)
structure(list(date = structure(c(2012, 2012.25, 2012.5, 2012.75, 
2013, 2013.25, 2013.5, 2013.75, 2014, 2014.25, 2014.5, 2014.75, 
2015, 2015.25, 2015.5, 2015.75, 2016, 2016.25, 2016.5, 2012, 
2012.25, 2012.5, 2012.75, 2013, 2013.25, 2013.5, 2013.75, 2014, 
2014.25, 2014.5, 2014.75, 2015, 2015.25, 2015.5, 2015.75, 2016, 
2016.25, 2016.5), class = "yearqtr"), variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("eff_int", "int"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(6.96419821086019, 7.14380786734124, 7.62285510953761, 
    8.38643647420047, 9.3298074353733, 9.39536175697088, 9.25562759246473, 
    9.01979842614537, 8.86956235820209, 8.71034537033914, 8.70483610509478, 
    8.86490412786529, 9.14046831486076, 9.25763491737298, 9.35166748435806, 
    9.61977735450941, 9.77846144170396, 9.79770969419896, 9.85126049926847, 
    10.7636292111401, 10.7026205049705, 9.83155682535731, 8.88716591127536, 
    7.27131536386736, 7.2219761501119, 9.51243063851385, 9.44429820351177, 
    8.41534119261688, 7.51079204000062, 6.82767573245953, 7.27469361353513, 
    15.2981698351549, 11.5648989165497, 9.18186633248605, 7.23361407952981, 
    7.09619633565995, 6.09043348368972, 5.33841979178199)), row.names = c(NA, 
-38L), .Names = c("date", "variable", "value"), class = "data.frame")

dput(p8_ch2_line_melt)
structure(list(date = structure(c(2012, 2012.25, 2012.5, 2012.75, 
2013, 2013.25, 2013.5, 2013.75, 2014, 2014.25, 2014.5, 2014.75, 
2015, 2015.25, 2015.5, 2015.75, 2016, 2016.25, 2016.5), class = "yearqtr"), 
    variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "debt_serv", class = "factor"), 
    value = c(10.8960973867467, 12.607562113883, 10.7487398451497, 
    9.89070432209185, 10.4942585698635, 7.75787413463193, 7.79618335620887, 
    7.85681809145533, 8.47139147230582, 15.2587567726622, 14.4634263544327, 
    15.8101561314042, 14.5915615542354, 17.8477420726091, 14.0181468565348, 
    16.2598789624509, 14.3942661723461, 14.0541133390243, 13.434090770495
    )), row.names = c(NA, -19L), .Names = c("date", "variable", 
"value"), class = "data.frame")
```

So, I have 2 questions for experts on this site: 
 1. What did I do wrong while creating this chart? 
 2. What literature would you recommend to read in order to form right logic for creating charts in ggplot?

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is your desired output? Do you want a single legend for color and shape?

Comment: Yes, I need a commonly used legend type: a single one for line and points so that it doesn't double keys and key labels.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the scales the same breaks and labels then ggplot will merge them (32 is a blank shape)

```
ggplot(p8_ch2_line_melt, aes(as.numeric(date), value, color = variable, shape = variable)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_point(data = p8_ch2_points_melt, size = 1) +
  scale_shape_manual(
    breaks= c('eff_int', 'int', 'debt_serv'),
    name = NULL,
    labels= c('Эффективная ставка, % годовых (левая ось)', 'Стоимость суверенных займов, % годовых (левая ось)', 'Обслуживание долга, % от ВВП (левая ось)'),
    values = c(32, 15, 14)) +
  scale_colour_manual (
    breaks= c('eff_int', 'int', 'debt_serv'), 
    name = NULL,
    labels= c('Эффективная ставка, % годовых (левая ось)', 'Стоимость суверенных займов, % годовых (левая ось)', 'Обслуживание долга, % от ВВП (левая ось)'),
    values = c('#4477AA', '#117733', '#332288'))
```

Comment: Thank you for help. It changed the chart although left keys in legend look like as if there were 3 lines on the plot: 2 with points and one just flat. Ideally I'd prefer to have 2 legend keys look like dots and one like a line. 
I hope I don't sound too opaque.